# Dispose instance

Tags: c#, dispose

Class1:

```
      public class FunctionBlocks
      { 
          List<Hashtable> _htLogicalNodeList;   
          public FunctionBlocks()
          { 
            _htLogicalNodeList = new List<Hashtable>();
            FunctionBlock fb = new FunctionBlock();
            fb.AddDODASignalList(new Hashtable);            
            _htLogicalNodeList.Add(fb.LogicalNodeHash);     
            fb = null;
          }     
      }
```

Class2:

```
      public class FunctionBlock
      {
        Hashtable _htLogicalNode;

        public FunctionBlock()
        {
            _htLogicalNode = new Hashtable();
        }

        public Hashtable LogicalNodeHash
        {
            get{return _htLogicalNode;}
            set{_htLogicalNode = value;}
        }

        public void AddDODASignalList(Hashtable doDASignal)
        {
            _htLogicalNode.Add(doDASignal);
        }
     }
```

In this example I wan't to dispose  "_htLogicalNode" . "fb" object I have make it as null ,Eventhough  "FunctionBlocks" instance have "_htLogicalNode" references. How I can dispose "_htLogicalNode" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "dispose"?  You could have `FunctionBlock` implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx#Y1583) in which case you could use the following:

```
using (FunctionBlock fb = new FunctionBlock())
{
    fb.AddDODASignalList(new Hashtable);            
    _htLogicalNodeList.Add(fb.LogicalNodeHash);     
}
```

However I can't see anything in `FunctionBlock` that needs disposing, and so doing this would be pointless - the `IDisposable` interface / pattern is essentially just a fancy / robust way of calling a method when you are done with an object.  Unless you do something in the implemented `Dispose` method then this does nothing.

If by "dispose" you mean free up the memory then the answer is that you don't need to do **anything** (you don't even need to set `fb` to null).  Simply let `fb` go out of scope and the garbage collector will collect it and free up the used memory in its own time.

You may find that the memory used by `fb` is not freed immediately - this is perfectly normal and to be expected.  There are ways of forcing the garbage collector into doing "its thing" when you want it to, but doing this is *very bad practice*.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx#Y1583

See the article above.

Answer (score 0):

Override dispose method and there you can make it null